# checkerboard into 6 spots and swap these after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create checker-box with 6 spot.3 white and 3 black; after 5 seconds then swap these over.

I have tried below code:

```js
var checkerBoard = [];
var space = 1;
for (var r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
  var col = "";
  for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    col += "<td data-pos='" + space + "'></td>";
    space++;
  }
  $("#gameBoard").append("<tr>" + col + "</tr>");
}
```

```css
#gameBoard {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

#gameBoard tr td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000;
}

#gameBoard tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #fff;
}

#gameBoard tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive container">
  <table class="table hide" id="gameBoard">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I don't know how to swap color in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just toggle a class in `#gameBoard` table in every 5 second using `setInterval` and then apply some css to that new class to change the background-color(or swap)

Also add some transition to `#gameBoard tr td` make it look smoother

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var checkerBoard = [];
var space = 1;
for (var r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
  var col = "";
  for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    col += "<td data-pos='" + space + "'></td>";
    space++;
  }
  $("#gameBoard").append("<tr>" + col + "</tr>");
}
setInterval(function() {
  $("#gameBoard").toggleClass("swap");
}, 5000);
```

```css
#gameBoard {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

#gameBoard tr td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#gameBoard tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #fff;
}

#gameBoard tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #fff;
}

#gameBoard.swap tr td {
  background: #fff;
}

#gameBoard.swap tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #000;
}

#gameBoard.swap tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive container">
  <table class="table hide" id="gameBoard">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But if you want to swap only once, not want to repeat....use `addClass()` instead of `toggleClass()` with `setTimeout()` like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#gameBoard").addClass("swap");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: set interval goes crazy if put it in loop. Can i clear interval in loop?

Answer (score 1):

Add another css class for reversed order, then add this class after 5 sec with seTimeout.

```js
var checkerBoard = [];
var space = 1;
for (var r=0; r<2; r++) {
    var col = "";
    for (var c=0; c<3; c++) { 
         col += "<td data-pos='"+space+"'></td>"; space++; 
    }
    $("#gameBoard").append("<tr>"+col+"</tr>");
}

setTimeout(function(){
 $("#gameBoard").addClass('reversed');
}, 5000)
```

```css
#gameBoard { 
  padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  border: 2px solid #000; 
}

#gameBoard tr td { 
  width: 60px; 
  height: 60px; 
  background: #000; 
}

#gameBoard tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1) { 
  background: #fff; 
}

#gameBoard tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) { 
  background: #fff; 
}

#gameBoard.reversed tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1) { 
  background: #000; 
}

#gameBoard.reversed tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) { 
  background: #000; 
}

#gameBoard.reversed tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n+1) { 
  background: #fff; 
}

#gameBoard.reversed tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n) { 
  background: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive container">
    <table class="table hide" id="gameBoard" >
       <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is also helpful.